# If concurrentHashMap is said to have "fail-safe" iterator (opposite to fail-fast), how come it still have most updated changes all the time?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, concurrency

In fail-safe iterator, (same as copyOnArrayList), where iterator has a copy of map, and all the operations will be done on this copy and not on actual map.(Correct me if my understanding is wrong). So how come in following code snippet,this copy has all the changes updated with actual map.

```
static Map<Integer, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String>();

static{
  map.put(1, "One");
  map.put(2, "Two");
  map.put(3, "Three");
  map.put(4, "Four");
  map.put(5, "Five");
}

Iterator itr = map.entrySet().iterator();

while(itr.hasNext()){
  Entry<Integer,String> entry= (Entry<Integer, String>) itr.next();
  System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " , " + entry.getValue() + " modified");
  map.remove(4);
}

System.out.println("Value of map "+map);


Output:
1 , One modified
2 , Two modified
3 , Three modified
5 , Five modified
Value of map {1=One, 2=Two, 3=Three, 5=Five}
```

According to my understanding of fail-safe iterator,

```
"4 , Four modified"
```

should come in output as  I have removed it from main map and not from its duplicate copy which iterator has generated.

Comment: The docs for entrySet say: The view's iterator is a "weakly consistent" iterator that will never throw ConcurrentModificationException, and guarantees to traverse elements as they existed upon construction of the iterator, **and may** (but is not guaranteed to) **reflect any modifications subsequent to construction.** (emphasis mine)

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` employs more than just fail safe iterator in order to increase concurrency (different tricks for different Java versions). Also please note that in your example there is only `main` thread  which operates on the map and the iterator, so there is no contention.

Comment: Exactly, I am removing element with key 4 from map, so how come it is surely all the time gets reflected in iterator's copy

Comment: Whoever told you about the copy seems to be wrong. The implementation and official docs say something different.

Comment: The term "fail safe" is not used anywhere in the Java SE specification. Whatever document used that term, and that led you to believe that the concurrent modification policy of CHM is the same as `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, is incorrect.